# How do I search for sub-items from a search query?

Tags: database, string, algorithm, array-algorithms

Let's say I have a search query for `'the black top hat the red shirt the blue top hat'`. Items `'the black top hat'` and `'the red shirt'` exist in an array, however, `'the blue top hat'` does not exist in the array. How would I search if the items exist in the array, because the items are all combined into one search string and are not separate.

Would I have to search for `'the', 'the black', 'the black top', ..., 'black', 'black top', etc...` or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
select ...
from ...
where mycol like '%the black top hat%'
and mycol like '%the red shirt%'
—- etc
```

to filter out rows with particular values:

```
and mycol not like '%the blue top hat%'
```

Comment: The search is a single string, so I can't know to split into 'the black top hat', 'the red shirt', and 'the blue top hat'.

Comment: @siddha this works with a single string. What do you mean exactly? Exactly what are examples of data in the table and variable search strings for the query?